# How to make button in Leaflet in Front of Map

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapping, react, button

I'm making a map using a leaflet. And, the button that i created cant in front of the map. How to make the button appear in front of the map?

this code in JSX :

```
<div className="bottom-0 right-0 mx-10 my-4">
    {editMode ? (
     <div className="flex justify-end z-400">
     <button onClick={(e) => toggleMapMode(false)}>Edit Mode</button>
     </div>
```

Comment: post some code of your problem

Comment: I've added some code in my previous question

Comment: You can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375163/19885851